# Unable to upload file in struts2 using Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am trying to upload a file in struts 2 using Jquery ajax.Using Form submit I am able to.Please help me on this.
The code for the JSP is given below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function upload()
{
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : 'userImage.action',
        dataType:'text',
        data:$("#uploadForm").serialize(),
        async:false,
        success : function(data) {
        alert(data)
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Struts2 File Upload & Save Example</h2>
<s:actionerror />
<form id="uploadForm" action="userImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userImage"  /><br>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="upload()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code given in struts2.xml is given below

```
<action name="userImage"
                    class="hart.bean.FileUploadAction">
                    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                        <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
                    </interceptor-ref>
                    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
                    <result name="success">SuccessUserImage.jsp</result>
                    <result name="input">UserImage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

And the code in action class is given below

```
    private File userImage;
    private String userImageContentType;
    private String userImageFileName;

    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public String execute() {
        try {
            String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getContextPath();
            System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath+" userimg=="+userImageFileName);
            File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);

            FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            addActionError(e.getMessage());

            return INPUT;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public File getUserImage() {
        return userImage;
    }

    public void setUserImage(File userImage) {
        this.userImage = userImage;
    }

    public String getUserImageContentType() {
        return userImageContentType;
    }

    public void setUserImageContentType(String userImageContentType) {
        this.userImageContentType = userImageContentType;
    }

    public String getUserImageFileName() {
        return userImageFileName;
    }

    public void setUserImageFileName(String userImageFileName) {
        this.userImageFileName = userImageFileName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I searched on the internet I found  that I cannot upload files using XMLHttpRequest (Ajax).So I used a jquery Form Plugin for the purpose.